# Why $|a_m - a_n| > \frac{a}{3}$?

Tags: real-analysis

> I'm reading Courant's: Differential and Integral Calculus. Here:

[image]
[image]

> I guess I understand the overall idea of the proof: If $|a_m-a_n|$ can be made arbitrarily small when $m,n$ are arbitrarily large and we have two points of accumulation $\eta, \xi$ with a fixed positive distance, we can have an even smaller $|a_m-a_n|$ which implies that the length of this interval will be smaller than the distance from $\eta$ to $\xi$ and this is a contradiction.
>
> I've been able to follow the proof until he argues that $|a_m - a_n| > \frac{a}{3}$. I don't see how he concluded that.

Comment: If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is an arbitrary choice such that $2\cdot\frac\alpha3<\alpha$

here is a sketch

[image]

Answer (score 2):

By the triangle inequality we have
$$
a=|\xi-\eta| \le |\xi-a_n| + |a_n-a_m| + |a_m-\eta| \le \frac{a}{3} + |a_n-a_m| + \frac{a}{3},
$$
and so
$$
|a_n-a_m| \ge a - \frac{2a}{3} = \frac{a}{3}.
$$

If two cities are 90 miles apart, and you are within 30 miles of one city, and your brother is within 30 miles of the other city, then you must be at least 30 miles apart from your brother.

Answer (score 1):

Let $|\xi-\eta| = a$

$\{a_i\}$ is cauchy so there is an $M$ where $m,n > M$ implies $|a_m - a_n| < \frac a3$.

$\xi$ is an accumulation point so there is an $N$ where $m > N$ implies $|\xi - a_m| < \frac a3$

$\eta$ is an accumulation point so there is an $K$ where $n>K$ implies $|\eta - a_n| < \frac a3$.

So if $m,n > \max (M,N,K)$ then

$a = |\xi - \eta| \le |\xi - a_m| + |a_m - a_n| + |a_n - \eta| < \frac a3 + \frac a3 + \frac a3= a$

That is a contradiction.

However the author took an slightly different route:

$ |\xi - \eta| \le |\xi - a_m| + |a_m - a_n| + |a_n - \eta|\implies$

$|a_m - a_n| \ge|\xi - \eta| -  |x_i - a_m| - |a_n - \eta|$

and

$|\xi - \eta| -  |x_i - a_m| - |a_n - \eta| > a - \frac a3 - \frac a3= \frac a3$

So $|a_m - a_n|> \frac a3$